# Unsaved managed object context produce exception on predicate containing NONE or ANY

Tags: ios, exception, core-data, predicate, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'd like to execute a fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];   
[fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES];        
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"TESTNAME",@"TEST", nil];        
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE name IN %@", set]];
```

when executing the request on an unsaved NSManagedObjectContext the app is terminated with exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'

If I save the context just before execution all works as expected. Any ideas on the reason for this?

Note: This happens on application launch when bundled data is imported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.
I have big predicate consisting from sub-predicates (with ANY inside), and after removing "ANY" subpredicate I do not get any crashes.

And how to save context if you are using autosave via UIManagedDocument ?

---

**---- Edited ----**

The issue was resolved simply by putting try/catch and reinitializing the predicate:

```
+ (NSArray *)productsByColorName:(NSString *)name {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [DatabaseController sharedInstance].database.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[[self class] tableName]];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K =[cd] %@", @"color.name", name];
    request.predicate = predicate;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = nil;

    @try {
        matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    } @catch (NSException *ex) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", [ex reason]);

        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K =[cd] %@", @"color.name", name];
        request.predicate = predicate;

        matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Seems like there an issue inside database which is working differently if context isn't saved after changes.

Probably I'm doing something wrong (fixing it by workaround) but this approach fixed my crash. Hopefully it will help others.